# onclick on img that would link to a particular section on another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

so currently I'm trying to link a particular section of another component page to an img when the image is clicked. Right now i'm doing this in the below component which takes me to the questions/1234 page but not to the exact section of questions/1234

```
handleClick(event) {
  this.props.history.push('/questions/1234')

}

render() {
     <img src={"/public/123"} onClick= {event => 
     this.handleImageClick(event)} className="thumbnail"/>
     />
 }
```

The component I'm linking the image to when clicked is

```
  render() {
      <div id="one">
          1
      </div>

      <div id="two">
          2
      </div>

      <div id="three">
          3
      </div>

  }
```

And i would like to make it so that when I click on the image in the first component, this would lead me to the div "two" of the other component. How can I do this?  Please Remember this is React

Comment: instead of putting a click on the image why not wrap this in a `Link` element that does the history push for you? this gives you the ability to use link builtin actions in the browser (like right click on the image and say open link in a new tab, for instance)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then this should be possible by specifying a hash in the path of the page being navigated to.

If the hash value matches an element `id` in the page being navigated to, then the browser should automatically scroll to that element to ensure it's visible:

```
handleClick(event) {
  /* 
  Adding #two causes browser to ensure that <div id="two"> is visible
  after navigation
  */
  this.props.history.push('/questions/1234#two');    
}
```

Comment: @jennielisajane just to confirm, are you using `react-router` here?

Comment: ok - my understanding is that is a library for the Angular framework?

Comment: @jennielisajane when you did this, did the url include the `#two` on the address bar of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code looks like reactjs, hence this answer.
What I have had to do in the past is use a library called `react-scrollable-anchor`. Check it out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollable-anchor)

So in your case it'll probably look like so:

```
import ScrollableAnchor from 'react-scrollable-anchor';

// your other stuffs...

 render() {
    return <ScrollableAnchor id="one">
      <div>
        1
      </div>
    </ScrollableAnchor>

    <ScrollableAnchor id="two">
      <div>
        2
      </div>
    </ScrollableAnchor>

    <ScrollableAnchor id="three">
      <div>
        3
      </div>
    </ScrollableAnchor>

  }
```

> Note: Your *render* methods look weird without a return.

In the off chance that you're using Angular, which I know very little about, you may check out this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll

Also, for something as simple as this you'll expect not to use another library on top of the routing library you already have, guess it's not that simple. Check these github thread out for:

- react (using react-router) => https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-220221604
- angular => https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14245

Additionally, your use of `onClick` event on the `img` tag feels a bit forced (js overuse) to me. Is there reason you're not doing as @John Rudell suggested in his/her/their comment? i.e wrapping your image in an anchor like so:

```
handleClick(event) {
  // Not today we're just going to use an anchor for this
  // this.props.history.push('/questions/1234')

}

render() {
   <a href="/questions/1234#two >
     <img src={"/public/123"} className="thumbnail" />
   </a>
 }
```

> Note: technically, there's talk that the above is not a valid html as per dom nesting rules. Nesting an inline-block inside of an inline element. There are solutions to this. I just didn't want to distract from the simple idea of using the right tools.

In case OP or anyone else is wondering, a solution might be:

```
render() {
  <div style={{ position: "relative" }} >
     <img src={"/public/123"} className="thumbnail" />
     <a
      href="/questions/1234#two
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: "100%"
    />
  </div>
 }
```

Hope it helps.